# Improving Lua error messages

Tags: debugging, lua

Whenever an error occurs in a Lua script, I'd like it to write the values of all local and global variables to the screen/optionally to a file - in addition to the usual stack trace.

How could I get this to be the default behavior for all errors?

Answer (score 4):

The [StackTracePlus](http://github.com/ignacio/StackTracePlus) module does what you want, displaying local variables at each level of the stack trace. It doesn't dump the entire globals table, but that is probably overkill.

To install it with LuaRocks, use

```
luarocks install stacktraceplus
```

Then in your code, do:

```
local STP = require "StackTracePlus"
debug.traceback = STP.stacktrace
```

In Lua 5.1 this will automatically convert all stack traces; for Lua 5.2 code you need to wrap your code with an `xpcall` as suggested in other answers.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using the standard Lua interpreter, replace `debug.traceback` with your own function. If you're embedding Lua in your program, use your traceback function in `lua_pcall`.

Comment: Thank you, I'll experiment with your recommendations. Related to this I see some references on mailing lists to "pcall and coroutines don't get along". I do use coroutines, should I use coxpcall and copcall?

Answer (score 1):

A more proper solution would be to use xpcall around your whole code.

```
local function myerrhandler ( errobj )
    print(debug.traceback())
    for k,v in pairs(_G) do print("GLOBAL:" , k,v) end
    return false
end

xpcall( function ()
--Your code here
end , myerrhandler )
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error handler may be overwritten. If you're calling Lua from C, to always print the stack you can hook in to the **luaG_errormsg** function.

In lua, write :

```
local _HandlingError = 0
function _ErrorHandler ( errobj )
    if( _HandlingError == 0 ) then
        _HandlingError = 1
        local errStr = tostring(errobj) or ""
        if( type(errobj)=='table' ) then
          errStr = "Table: {" .. table.concat(errobj, ',') .. "}"
        end
        print("Error: \"" .. errStr .. "\"")
        --for k,v in pairs(_G) do print("GLOBAL:" , k,v) end
        if( type(errobj)=='thread' ) then
            print(debug.traceback(errobj))
        else
            print(debug.traceback('',2))
        end
        _HandlingError = 0
    end
    return false
end
```

Then in **ldebug.c**, add to **luaG_errormsg** after **if(L->errfunc != 0)**

```
else
{
    lua_getfield(L, LUA_GLOBALSINDEX, "_ErrorHandler");
    if (!lua_isfunction(L, -1)) {
        lua_pop(L, 1);
    }
    else {
        lua_pushvalue(L, 1);
        lua_call(L, 2, 1);
        lua_pop(L, 1);
    }
}
```